# Spring JsonIgnore inactive leads to infinite loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I catch infinitive loop, and cannot create JSON success. I have 2 tables

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "size")
public class CSize {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "size")
    private String size;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "product_size", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "size_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") })
    private Set<CProduct> products = new HashSet<>();}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class CProduct {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private Long price;

    @Column(name = "discount")
    private Long discount;

    @Column(name = "stock")
    private Long stock;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_create")
    private Date dateCreate;

    @Column(name = "featured")
    private boolean featured = false;

    @Column(name = "url_img")
    private String url_img;

    @Column(name = "description", length = 2000)
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products")
    private Set<CSize> sizes = new HashSet<>();}
```

What I desire is that when I retrieve a list of CProduct, it should include fields from CSize, but within the CSize object, it should not include the product field. However, in reality, the CSize object still includes the product field, forming an infinite loop.

[image]

Disable infinite loop.

Comment: And that's just one of the reasons why the good practice is to use `DTO`s, not to serialize/deserialize entities.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like these samples

```java
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable( name = "user_product",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"))
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Product> listOfProductsForUser;
```

and/or

```java
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "listOfProductsForUser")

@JsonBackReference
private List<User> listOfUsersForProduct;
```

focus at `@JsonManagedReference` and `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`

Comment: I have tried as you instructed, `` @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "products")
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<CSize> sizes;``

but @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference cause the entire CSize list to be lost when I attempt to convert the JSON list of CSize linked to CProduct. Is there a way to help me convert the JSON list of CSize linked to CProduct without including the product field in the CSize object?